# How to remove all items containing a string in Windows registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I am trying to remove all reference to 'Business Objects' on my machine as my previous install was not right and doesnt give option to uninstall.

I am able to delete one by one with find next (<kbd>F3</kbd> => and delete), but this takes long time.

Is there a good way to search all references and delete them all at a time?

I am on Windows 2008 Server R2.

Comment: programmatically?

Comment: Not sure how can this be acheived programmatcially.  Is there any vb script to do this? or is done differently ?

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with [Nirsoft's RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) - seems way faster than F3 in regedit.exe.

Answer (score 1):

When uninstalling, use RevoUninstaller and then CCleaner. This'll get just about every reference relatively safely.

Comment: [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html)

Comment: Thx for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I use [**Registry Workshop**](http://www.torchsoft.com/en/rw_information.html).  You can use the free trial to search for entries and delete them.